# error saying variable is not defined in a function in python

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a simple function to take a char out of a user input in python but keep getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chris/Desktop/Python_Stuff/replace.py", line 4, in <module>
    new= old.replace("*","")
NameError: name 'old' is not defined
```

This is my code:

```
def remove_char(old):
    old =input("enter a word that includes * ")
    return old #do I even need this?
new= old.replace("*","")
print (new)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: can you pls refine your function indentation?

Comment: Yes, you always need this. Since function returns values and procedures perform operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use a method in *old* variable, because you never defined this variable before. (*old* is defined and visible just in the function, not outside).
You do not really need a function to input the word.
Try this:

```
old = raw_input('enter a word that includes * ')
new= old.replace("*","")
print (new)
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I noticed I didn't need the function, I was just trying to gain a better understanding! I probably chose the wrong example. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Your function's *returning a value*. Please do not ignore it.

```
def remove_char(old):
   old =input("enter a word that includes * ")
   return old

new= remove_char(old).replace("*","") 
print (new)
```

Yes, you may not need `return`:

```
old=None
def remove_char():
   global old
   old =input("enter a word that includes * ")

remove_char() # NOTE: you MUST call this first!
new= old.replace("*","") 
print (new)
```

---

**Note**: I agree with @jonrsharpe - the second example shows one of the ugliest ways to achieve what you want! You asked whether you can omit `return` - yes, but you'd better *do not*.

Comment: Why on earth would you provide the `global` version?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, OP asked if it was possible to remove `return` - yes, it is - with globals

Comment: At the **very least**, you should point out that that is a *terrible* way of writing the program...

Comment: The wrong answer to this question is: "Because I can". The right version: True, why the hell I did that!?